# Problema de punteros en Java. POO

Tags: java, poo, punteros

Tengo un problema con este ejercicio. No sé como enlazar las clases Datos y Cuenta para utilizar los getters en el toString().

La resolución que debo mostrar por pantalla es: nombre del titular, dni y saldo.

Gracias de antemano.

Un saludo.

```
package tareaUnidad3Punteros;

public class Arranque {
    
    Datos dato1=new Datos("Pepe","123456789A");
    Cuenta cuenta1=new Cuenta(1000d);
    
    public Arranque() {
        
        cuenta1.toString();
        
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Arranque p=new Arranque();

    }

}

public class Datos {
    
    private String dni;
    private String nombre;
    
    public Datos(String dni, String nombre) {
        this.dni = dni;
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public String getDni() {
        return dni;
    }

    public void setDni(String dni) {
        this.dni = dni;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

}

public class Cuenta {
    
    private double saldo;

    public Cuenta(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }
    
    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "El titular de la cuenta es "+Datos.getNombre()+", su DNI es "+Datos.getDni()+" y su saldo es de "+saldo;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hay varias maneras de hacerlo, pero por buena practica es recomendado utilizar la **composición** en java.

> La composición es el agrupamiento de uno o varios objetos  y valores, como atributos.

Pasamos el objeto Datos en el constructor para inicializar el atributo en la clase Cuenta.

```java
public class Cuenta {
    
    private double saldo;
    private Datos datos;

    public Cuenta(double saldo, Datos datos) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
        this.datos = datos;
    }
    
    public double getSaldo() {
        return saldo;
    }

    public void setSaldo(double saldo) {
        this.saldo = saldo;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "El titular de la cuenta es "+datos.getNombre()+", su DNI es "+datos.getDni()+" y su saldo es de "+saldo;
    }
```

```java
    public Arranque() {
       Datos dato1=new Datos("Pepe","123456789A");
       Cuenta cuenta1=new Cuenta(1000d, dato1); 
       cuenta1.toString(); 
    }
```

Comment: Yo sólo añadiría que, conceptualmente, la clave es revisar cuándo una entidad requiere hacer ésto mismo, contener como atributo a otra clase para expresar mejor una relación, sin extender innecesariamente las responsabilidades de la clase que agrupa.